# Are pull-down resistors included in the mbed USB ports?

Tags: usb, resistors, mbed, usb-host

For the mbed LPC 1768, I am trying to establish a USB connection with an external device (pins 31, 32, and 39 for D+, D-, and V<sub>bus</sub>, respectively). According to [USB in a NutShell: Connectors](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml), a 15kΩ resistor must be connected to D+ and D-. Are these resistors included within the mbed, or will they have to be connected externally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LPC1768 USB controller is capable of acting as host, device, or even dynamically switching (On-The-Go).  Since these resistors need to be on the host side only, it wouldn't make sense to include them on a development kit (if you did, you lose the ability to act as a USB device).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to add them yourself; the mbed LPC1768 [schematic](http://mbed.org/media/uploads/chris/mbed-005.1.pdf) doesn't show them on-board.